# How to get the index of an element under its parent?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here's my HTML:

```
<p><a><img src='#'></img></a><a href='#'>Second Anchor</a>
```

I'm trying to remove the anchor around the first image. The approach I'm thinking about is: finding the image, find the grandparent `<p>`, extract the parent anchor, and insert the image into the grandparent. The problem is that I don't know which position to insert the image into. So I need to know the position of its parent anchor in its grandparent paragraph.

Comment: Use beautiful soup 4 and the [`unwrap`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) method.

Comment: @beerbajay you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `replaceWithChildren` method (BeautifulSoup 3):

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("<p><a><img src='#'></img></a><a href='#'>Second Anchor</a>")
>>> soup.find("img").parent.replaceWithChildren()
>>> print soup
<p><img src="#" /><a href="#">Second Anchor</a></p>
```

Comment: This is outdated, even if it is the previously-best answer.

Comment: @beerbajay BeautifulSoup 3.2 is the version distributed by most Linux distributions, so I thought it could be relevant anyway. I am not much experienced with BS 4, I agree you should post the `unwrap` comment as an answer.